# Is this the best fluent nhibernate fetching strategy?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate, fetch

I have a Person table that has many fields that are foreign keys into other tables

So i have to make a choice to do this:

```
   References(x => x.Field1).Fetch.Join();
   References(x => x.Field2).Nullable().Fetch.Join();
   References(x => x.Field3).Nullable().Fetch.Join();
   References(x => x.Field4).Nullable().Fetch.Join();
```

or

```
   References(x => x.Field1).Fetch.Select();
   References(x => x.Field2).Nullable().Fetch.Select();
   References(x => x.Field3).Nullable().Fetch.Select();
   References(x => x.Field4).Nullable().Fetch.Select();
```

I see that the first one will do an outer join against all of the other table and the second one will not.  I am running tests with nhibernate profiler but I am trying to get a rule of thumb or best practice on when you should use Fetch.Select() (can't find a lot on the web).

I assume if i want to access another field in Field2 table for all entries i am better off doing upfront join and if i might not be accessing data from these associated tables to do the second

Are there other factors that come into play in this decision that i am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delay that decision until the use case, because it has a lot more context and each usecase will have other requirements. So:

- use the default Fetchmode for all References which are different per use case
- use `Join()` on special cases like polymorphic references or always needed references
- use `Fetch(x => x.Fieldx).Eager` on queries to explicit eager load for the specific use case